# Out of Curiosity: Why is python3 not using __dict__ compare as the default equality implementation?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python (I am using v 3.4) one may test two objects for equality using `this == that` as one might in most other languages.

When comparing class based objects, python refers to the `__eq__`method of the class for said comparison.

However, doing something like the following example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar

one = Foo('text')
two = Foo('text')
```

Calling `one == two` will yield `False`, since python does only check for identity, rather than data equality.

This leads to the fact that you end up implementing a lot of `__eq__` and `__ne__` (not equals) methods **exactly** like this:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return (isinstance(other, self.__class__)
        and self.__dict__ == other.__dict__)

def __ne__(self, other):
    return not self.__eq__(other)
```

Why do we have to do this?

Does anybody know, why they decided against implementing the dict-compare method as default for class based objects?

What could be the negatives of this approach?

Comment: If you define your `__eq__`, `__ne__` methods in a base class and make your other classes inherit the base class, then you will not have to repeat the definition in lots of places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why do we have to do this?

Because explicit is better than implicit.

You are making an assumption that instances are equal solely based on their attributes; this is not necessarily the rule. Take classes that use private attributes tracking cached data, for example. And what about classes that have a large number of attributes but do not need to support equality? Why would they need to pay the extra performance penalty?

Rather than make such assumptions, Python asks you to define equality explicitly. This has the added advantage that you don't then need to *disable* such equality tests again if you do *not* want to support equality between instances.

For simple cases it is fine to use `vars(self)` or `self.__dict__`, sure:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, __class__):
        return NotImplemented
    return vars(self) == vars(other)

def __ne__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, __class__):
        return NotImplemented
    return not self.__eq__(other)
```

Returning `NotImplemented` ensures that the other object is also given a chance to implement an equality test.

Comment: Or... `def __ne__(self, other): return not self.__eq__(other)` for mirroring...?

Comment: @JonClements: You still want to return `NotImplemented` explicitly. `not NotImplemented` returns `False`, not the sentinel.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.

Also thanks for the tip, using ```NotImplemented```. I didn't know, python's default behavior involved asking the other object for an ```__eq__``` method, if that is thrown. That is awesome.

Comment: @Hr.Rabe: Not thrown, returned; it is a singleton object like `None`, not an exception. :-)