# Recommended way to implement __eq__ and __hash__

Tags: python, equality, hashable

The [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) mentions that if you override `__eq__` and the object is immutable, you should also override `__hash__` in order for the class to be properly hashable.

In practice, when I do this I often end up with code like

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if type(other) is type(self):
            return (self.a == other.a) and (self.b == other.b)
        else:
            return False

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.a, self.b))
```

This is somewhat repetitive, and there is a clear risk of forgetting to update one when the other is updated.

Is there a recommended way of implementing these methods together?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Answering my own question. It seems one way of performing this is to define an auxillary `__members` function and to use that in defining `__hash__` and `__eq__`. This way, there is no duplication:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __members(self):
        return (self.a, self.b)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if type(other) is type(self):
            return self.__members() == other.__members()
        else:
            return False

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.__members())
```

Comment: there's a risk here that `self.a` or `self.b` change, which causes the hash to change (which breaks all sorts of things)

Comment: @raylu can you explain more ?

Comment: `one = MyClass(1, 1); stuff = {one}; print(one in stuff); print(MyClass(2, 2) in stuff); one.a = one.b = 2; print(MyClass(2, 2) in stuff); print(MyClass(2, 2) in list(stuff))`

this prints `True`, `False`, `False`, `True`. (2, 2) is "not" in the set `stuff` but it's in `list(stuff)`, which doesn't use `__hash__`

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26641360/4368898), `vars(self)` or `self.__dict__` could be used instead of manually defining `self.__members`. But note that they both return dictionaries which are mutable and not hashable. To use a dictionary with `__hash__`, review the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25176504/4368898): `hash(tuple(sorted(self.__dict__.items())))`.

Answer (score -1):

Is that the equivalent of this one-liner **eq**?

```
   def __eq__(self, other):
       return type(other) is type(self) and (self.a == other.a) and (self.b == other.b)
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you can use user defined hash function is better.

```
class MyClass(object):

def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b

def __eq__(self, other):
    if type(other) is type(self):
        return (self.a, self.b) == (other.a, other.b)
    else:
        return NotImplemented

def __hash__(self):
    return hash((self.a, self.b))
```

Comment: This will give the wrong result for e.g. `MyClass(2, -2) == MyClass(-2, 2)` because of [hash collision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21743781/12299000) in CPython. You should never use `hash(a) == hash(b)` to decide whether `a` and `b` are equal.

Comment: Yes, it's my fault. I fixed the code