# How do I create a hash function that will return True if any of the fields match?

Tags: python

I have this class. The goal of this class is to encapsulate the logic for custom set operations:

```
class Reach(object):

    def __init__(self, device_id=None, user_id=None):
        self.device_id = device_id
        self.user_id = user_id

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Reach):
            # print(self.device_id, self.user_id)
            # print(other.device_id, other.user_id)
            return self.device_id == other.device_id or \
                    self.user_id == other.user_id
        return False

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(f"device_id={self.device_id}&user_id={self.user_id}")
```

This is my test case:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Basic equality test
    p1 = Reach(device_id="did1")
    p2 = Reach(device_id="did1", user_id="tauid1")
    assert p1 == p2
    s1 = set([p1])
    s2 = set([p2])
    assert len(s1 & s2) == 1                # Failing here 

    # Transmutivity test
    p1 = Reach(device_id="did1")
    p2 = Reach(device_id="did1", user_id="tauid1")
    p3 = Reach(user_id="tauid1")
    assert p1 != p3                                   
    assert p1 == p2 == p3
    s1, s2, s3 = set([p1]), set([p2]), set([p3])
    assert len(s1 & s3) == 0
    assert len(s1 | s3) == 2
    assert len(s1 & s2) == 1
    assert len(s2 & s3) == 1
    assert len(s1 & s2 & s3) == 1
    assert len(s1 | s2 | s3) == 1
```

I realized that since python set operations uses hash, `assert len(s1 & s2) == 1` fails because it's comparing the hash of `device_id=did1&user_id=None` with `device_id=did1&user_id=tauid1` which is not the same

What do I need to change to achieve my desired effect?

Comment: This seems smelly to me.  What if you have a set containing `[(a, b), (c, b), (c, d)]`?  If `(a, b)` hashes to the same as `(c, b)`, and `(c, b)` hashes to the same as `(c, d)`... I think you can use induction to prove that *all* items should have the same hash.

Comment: Expanding my example, removing `(c, b)` would have to effectively change the hash values of `(a, b)` and/or `(c, d)`.  And having a hash function that can change as a side-effect of some other operation is certainly a bad idea.

Comment: Minor note regarding your question's title:  `__hash__` is not going to return True (it returns an integer). It's the `__eq__` method that would return True if two objects are equal.

Comment: Regarding the title, the hash function *never* returns True; it returns an integer. Computing a hash for an object depends on that object only, not its relationship to any other object.

Comment: Related (dupe?) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69396676/how-to-implement-hash-for-an-object-with-multiple-comparable-properties

Answer (score 2):

This is easily accomplished, but the result is pretty much useless. Suppose we have four strings `a`, `b`, `x`, and `y`.

You want `Reach(a, b)` to have the same hash as `Reach(a, y)`, because the objects compare equal via your `__eq__`, and for a hash to be of any use at all object equality has to imply hash equality.

But for the same reason, you also need the hashes of `Reach(a, y)` and `Reach(x, y)` to be equal.

So for any four strings, you need

```
    hash(Reach(a, b)) == hash(Reach(x, y))
```

The only way to achieve that is with a hash function that's a constant, ignoring its argument. Like

```
def __hash__(self):
    return 12345
```

That will "work", but set operations will degenerate into extra-slow versions of linear search (all objects will map to the same hash bucket, and the same collision chain).

Comment: Actually this is exactly what i need. I am now failing the very last test`assert len(s1 | s2 | s3) == 1` probably because the end product of `s1 & s2` is `p1` rather than `p2`. Is there a way to force the set class to pick `p2` over `p1`?

Comment: Nope, there's no way to force any internal decision here. If I were you ;-), I'd rethink the base approach. As is, your definition of equality is nearly impossible to reason about. For example, you have `p1 == p2` and `p2 == p3`, but _not_ `p1 == p3`, a basic failure of transitivity. And, of course, you also want `len(s1 | s2 | s3) == 1` despite that you _also_ want `len(s1 | s3) == 2`. It's extremely surprising that folding another (`s2`) set into a union would _decrease_ the union's size. But, if that's what you think you want, you'll be best off implementing your own set type.

Comment: Thank you @Tim Peters for your help. This is actually being used in advertising to count the number of overlaps between two sets of users. Some users will have device_ids, some with user_ids and some with both.