Algorithm for binary search of the range of files in which the string occurs
I have a list of sorted files:
files = [file_1, file_2, file_3, file_4, file_5, file_6, file_7, file_8, file_9, file_10]

And there is a string whose presence I need to determine in these files. Usually this string is found in a certain range. For example, from file_1 to file_4, or from file_3 to file_10.
At the moment, I am looping through this list and opening each file in turn and checking for the presence of the string in it. But this is slow, because there are thousands of strings to search for, and there are more than 50 files in which it should be searched.
So I came up with an idea to search for a range not one by one, but using a binary search.
As I see it:
The first and last files in the list are opened first. If a string is present in both of them, then the range for this string is the whole list of files. If the string is present in the first file, but not in the last one, then the first file becomes the beginning of the range, and the end is now the file in the middle of the list. And so on.
I've tried to implement it according to the principle of the well-known binary search algorithm, but realized that their implementation does not coincide at all. But I don't have enough brains to write such an algorithm.
Can anyone help me? At least with pseudocode.

Usually doesn't really help much unless you are willing to bet on it... What string search algorithm are you using (KMP)?

Sorting the files doesn't help if you're searching for a substring of the contents.

So you can't use binary search for it. You need some kind of index to make this efficient.

Yes, you can use something like the binary search, but not exactly it because the list [False, False, True, True, False, False] is not sorted. Here is the idea : 1) use a bisect-like to find the first file (leftmost) in which the string is present 2) then bisect-like on the right-half to find the first file (leftmost) not containing it (or alternatively the last file (rightmost) containing it) 3) add lazyness and memoization for performance 4) done

Otherwise, it could be possible to use git-bisect. By creating (with a Python script) a commit history with the increasing file numbers, then run the git-bisect exec with a well-crafted bash command (or other program) to grep the file named like the current commit being bissected.

I don't think you can avoid the O(n) worst case; what no files where the substring was found exist, you would nave to check all files anyway, it doesn't matter what order you do it in, in this case.

Here is an answer :
import bisect
import platform
from functools import lru_cache
from pathlib import Path
from statistics import mean, median
from typing import Sequence, Generator, TypeVar, Any

import pytest  # only required for parametric tests


# NOTE: the `key` parameter has been added to `bisect` in Python 3.10, so
#       if it needs to work on Python < 3.10, then the `files` sequence itself
#       would have to be reversed, and indexes treated accordingly.
#       Because it is confusing to implement, I prefer not trying.
assert platform.python_version_tuple() >= ("3", "10", "0")


class File:
    def __init__(self, filepath: Path) -> None:
        self._path = filepath
        # memoization at the instance-level
        self.contains_string = lru_cache(maxsize=None)(self.contains_string)

    def contains_string(self, s: str) -> bool:
        return s in self._path.read_text()

    def __repr__(self) -> str:  # for convenience
        name = self._path.name
        return f"File({name=!r})"

    __str__ = __repr__

    @property
    def cache_info(self) -> tuple[int, int, int, int]:
        """hits, misses, maxsize, currsize"""
        return self.contains_string.cache_info()

    @property
    def __members(self) -> tuple[Any, ...]:  # cf https://stackoverflow.com/a/45170549/11384184
        return self._path,

    # required by https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-cache-method-calls

    def __eq__(self, other) -> bool:
        if isinstance(other, File):
            return self.__members == other.__members

    def __hash__(self) -> int:
        return hash(self.__members)


def create_bool_seq_for_test(start_index, end_index, length) -> Sequence[bool]:
    assert 0 <= start_index <= end_index < length
    before = [False] * start_index
    between = [True] * (end_index - start_index + 1)
    after = [False] * (length - end_index - 1)
    result = before + between + after
    assert len(result) == length
    return result


NUMBER_OF_PARAMETRIC_TESTS_CUBED = 5  # /!\ will result in ~cubed (^3) number of tests
# N=1   --> 1      test
# N=5   --> 34     tests
# N=10  --> 219    tests
# N=20  --> 1539   tests
# N=50  --> 22099  tests
# N=100 --> 171699 tests


STRING_PRESENT = "STRING IS PRESENT"
STRING_ABSENT = "nope"


class Test:
    def test_sample_case(self, tmp_path: Path) -> None:
        # Given
        expected_start_at_index = 46
        expected_end_at_index = 48
        length = 100
        files = self.create_files_for_test(
            create_bool_seq_for_test(expected_start_at_index, expected_end_at_index, length),
            tmp_path
        )
        s = STRING_PRESENT
        # When
        actual_start, actual_end = find_start_and_end_indexes(files, s)
        # Then
        assert (expected_start_at_index, expected_end_at_index) == (actual_start, actual_end)
        assert (expected_start_at_index, expected_end_at_index) == self.oracle(files, s)  # sanity check

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "expected_start_at_index,expected_end_at_index,length,presences",
        (
            (start_index, end_index, length, create_bool_seq_for_test(start_index, end_index, length))
            for length in range(1, NUMBER_OF_PARAMETRIC_TESTS_CUBED+1)
            for start_index in range(length)
            for end_index in range(start_index, length)
        )
    )
    def test_parametric(self, expected_start_at_index: int,
                        expected_end_at_index: int, length: int, presences: Sequence[bool], tmp_path: Path) -> None:
        """Parametric test for all combinations of start/end/length."""
        files = self.create_files_for_test(presences, tmp_path)
        assert (expected_start_at_index, expected_end_at_index) == \
               find_start_and_end_indexes(files, STRING_PRESENT)

    def test_performance(self, tmp_path: Path) -> None:
        # Given
        expected_start_at_index = 21
        expected_end_at_index = 27
        length = 100
        files = self.create_files_for_test(
            create_bool_seq_for_test(expected_start_at_index, expected_end_at_index, length),
            tmp_path
        )
        s = STRING_PRESENT

        # When
        find_start_and_end_indexes(files, s)
        hits_sut, misses_sut, _, _ = zip(
            *tuple(file.cache_info for file in files)
        )

        for file in files:
            file.contains_string.cache_clear()

        self.oracle(files, s)
        hits_oracle, misses_oracle, _, _ = zip(
            *tuple(file.cache_info for file in files)
        )

        # Then
        mean_hits_sut, median_hits_sut = \
            mean(hits_sut), median(hits_sut)
        mean_misses_sut, median_misses_sut = \
            mean(misses_sut), median(misses_sut)

        mean_hits_oracle, median_hits_oracle = \
            mean(hits_oracle), median(hits_oracle)
        mean_misses_oracle, median_misses_oracle = \
            mean(misses_oracle), median(misses_oracle)

        print(f"{mean_hits_sut=!r} {median_hits_sut=!r}")
        print(f"{mean_misses_sut=!r} {median_misses_sut=!r}")
        print(f"{mean_hits_oracle=!r} {median_hits_oracle=!r}")
        print(f"{mean_misses_oracle=!r} {median_misses_oracle=!r}")

        assert mean_hits_sut >= mean_hits_oracle  # we may re-use some previous results
        assert mean_misses_sut < mean_misses_oracle  # we do fewer reads (misses)

    def test_split_range_recursively(self) -> None:
        for size in range(1, 100+1):
            r = range(size)
            values = tuple(  # consume all
                iter_bisect_like(r)
            )
            assert sorted(values) == list(r)

    @staticmethod
    def oracle(files: Sequence[File], s: str) -> tuple[int, int]:
        # using a dumb way
        start_index = None
        end_index = None
        has_started = False
        for i, file in enumerate(files):
            is_present = file.contains_string(s)
            if is_present and not has_started:
                has_started = True
                start_index = i
            elif has_started and not is_present:
                end_index = i - 1
                break
        if start_index is None:
            raise ValueError("start_index not found")
        elif end_index is None:
            raise ValueError("end_index not found")
        else:
            return start_index, end_index

    @staticmethod
    def create_files_for_test(presences: Sequence[bool], dirpath: Path) -> Sequence[File]:
        files = []
        for i, is_present in enumerate(presences):
            filepath = dirpath / f"File_{i!s}.txt"
            filepath.write_text(STRING_PRESENT if is_present else STRING_ABSENT)
            files.append(File(filepath))
        return files


def find_start_and_end_indexes(files: Sequence[File], s: str) -> tuple[int, int]:
    # step 1 : find any True value (somewhere in the middle of the run)
    some_present_index = next(i for i in iter_bisect_like(range(len(files)))
                              if files[i].contains_string(s))
    # step 2 : find the leftmost True value to the left
    start_index = find_the_leftmost_true_value(files, hi=some_present_index, s=s)
    # step 3 : find the rightmost True value to the right
    end_index = find_the_rightmost_true_value(files, lo=some_present_index, s=s)
    return start_index, end_index


def find_the_leftmost_true_value(files: Sequence[File], hi: int, s: str) -> int:
    assert False < True  # in Python, booleans are actually integers 0 and 1
    assert (0, 1) == (False, True)  # proof
    # because we are searching for a False before a True, it is pretty simple
    return bisect.bisect_left(files, True, hi=hi,
                              key=lambda file: file.contains_string(s))


def find_the_rightmost_true_value(files: Sequence[File], lo: int, s: str) -> int:
    assert False < True  # in Python, booleans are actually integers 0 and 1
    assert (0, 1) == (False, True)  # proof
    # because we are searching for a True before a False, the order is reversed
    # for that, we need to provide a key to reverse the order
    # and pretend we want to try to insert a False
    # we need to `-1` because it returns the index **one after** the rightmost
    return bisect.bisect_right(files, False, lo=lo,
                               key=lambda file: not file.contains_string(s)
                               ) - 1


T = TypeVar("T")


def iter_bisect_like(values: Sequence[T]) -> Generator[T, None, None]:
    """
    Produces in a bisect-like manner the values from the sequence.
    Example: split_range_recursively(range(101)) yields
             50, 25, 75, 12, 38, 63, 88, 6, 19, ...
    """
    all_ranges_left = [range(len(values))]
    while len(all_ranges_left) != 0:
        r = all_ranges_left.pop(0)
        assert r.start < r.stop  # sanity check
        # find the middle point
        middle_index = (r.start + r.stop) // 2
        left_remaining_range = range(r.start, middle_index)
        right_remaining_range = range(middle_index + 1, r.stop)
        if len(left_remaining_range) != 0:
            all_ranges_left.append(left_remaining_range)
        if len(right_remaining_range) != 0:
            all_ranges_left.append(right_remaining_range)
        yield values[middle_index]
    return  # end of the generator

What I have done :

created a File class, that stores the path to the text file to search into, but with memoization (cache) for each different string
a function to create test sequences of Falses then Trues then Falses
a test method to create the files corresponding to these True/False sequences
a sample test
a parametric test to check that the code is functionnaly valid for all the possible combinations
an "oracle" that implements the sequential check
a performance test, that fails for some values (for example the oracle is very fast when the string is only contained in a few of the first files)
a function to iterate over values in bisect-like manner, which is used for the core algorithm find_start_and_end_indexes

I assumed that you will reuse the same files to search for different strings. If that is not the case, the code may have to be adapted but this should not be too difficult.
Further performance improvements could be implemented by using heuristics instead of a plain binary search, but that requires knowledge about the files' nature, which I don't have.
